# Windows Server 2012: use GPO in multiple OU's but only for specific servers

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012, windows

sample:

```
OU: A
User1
User2
GPO1

OU: B
User 3
User 4
GPO1

OU: C
Server1
Server2
Server3
```

Now i want to restrict GPO1 to Server1 and Server2 -> how can i do this in a easy/smart way?

thx

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! There appears to be little to no research done on this issue up front.  It is recommended that you post things you've already tried, options you are considering, or errors that you are experiencing.  The more details you provide (logs, screenshots, etc.), the better the experts here can assist you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah, you use the Security Filtering and/or WMI Filtering portions of Group Policy Management.

[image]

For example, you could use security filtering to ensure the GPO only applies to the `Server1` and `Server2` computer accounts, or use WMI filtering to make sure the GPO only applies to a certain Operating System or configuration that's unique to `Server1` and `Server2`.

Sounds like Security Filtering is easiest for your particular use case, but WMI filtering would be easiest if you wanted to (for example) apply a certain power plan to **only** laptops in your environment.

Comment: -1 for using the circle tool.